# represent numpy ellipsis

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I know how to slice array with numpy, for example

```
v[1, :, :]
```

now I want a function taking as input the slice `(1,1,None)` and returning `v[1,:,:]`

the problem is that I don't know how to represent ellipses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
slice(None)
```

all of these are equivalent:

```
v[1, :, :]
v[1, Ellipsis, Ellipsis]
v[1, slice(None), slice(None)]
v[(1, Ellipsis, Ellipsis)]
v[(1, slice(None), slice(None))]
```

the last two are what I need.

Comment: Those are equivalent if v has at least three dimensions.

Answer (score 5):

You can represent ellipses with `Ellipsis`.

It is mentioned [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/bltin-ellipsis-object.html)

Comment: @larsmans: You're right. A terminology faux pas on my part. edited.